# SSIS Process XML document in Excel Workbook format

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

I'm trying to import an XML document using SSIS that is exported using a Microsoft Office Excel format with 17 columns.  I have an XML task that is removing the multiple namespaces, but now I have a document that is formatted like the sample code below. I can load each Cell into it's own record in the database, but since there are no tags inside the row or cell sections, I have a database table with one column for each Cell.  I don't have any row numbers so not sure if I can do some sort of pre-sort, or if I'm going to have to do a bunch of SQL based on the row number being a multiple of 17 and STUFF FOR XML PATH the rows via temp tables which seems messy.

```
<Worksheet>
  <Table>
  <Column/>
    <Row>
      <Cell StyleID="s62">
        <Data Type="String">City</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell StyleID="s62">
        <Data Type="String">State</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell StyleID="s62">
        <Data Type="String">Zip</Data>
      </Cell>
    </Row>
  </Table>
</Worksheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know, if I understood this correctly...

Assuming your XML is in a variable `DECLARE @xml XML` you might get the Cells by calling them with their position within the tree

```
SELECT R.value('Cell[1]/Data[1]','varchar(max)') AS City
      ,R.value('Cell[2]/Data[1]','varchar(max)') AS State
      ,R.value('Cell[3]/Data[1]','varchar(max)') AS Zip
      --add more
FROM @xml.nodes('/Worksheet/Table/Row') AS A(R)
```

or you might think about pivot like this

```
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT 'Cell_' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS ColumnName
          ,Cell.value('Data[1]','varchar(max)') AS Data
    FROM @xml.nodes('/Worksheet/Table/Row/Cell') AS A(Cell)
) AS tbl
PIVOT
(
    MIN(Data) FOR ColumnName IN(Cell_1,Cell_2,Cell_3,Cell_4 /*add as many as you need*/)
) AS p;
```

The second could be transfered into dynamic SQL to analyse the existing Cell nodes, get their names and number and return a resultset fitting to the XML's data...

The last you would need, if the XML's data is not the same in all calls...

Comment: I hadn't thought of loading into an XML variable in the database and trying to parse from in there, I was trying to handle it in the SSIS dataflow.  I'll try bulk loading it in and see how it looks.  Thanks

Comment: You can bulk load an xml file into avariable directly. Search for openrowset and xml and file. There are many examples ...

Comment: The format has a max column count so I'm using your first suggestion with an OUTER APPLY to get all the values and split out the node data.  I'm having an issue accessing a Cell attribute that tells Excel an Index of a column (<Cell Index="17">) but I'll make a new question if I can't fight my way through.  -Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found was to open the file with script task using interop and save it in excel format.